# Probability - urn problem (drawing with putting back)

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

In an urn are $N-1$ white and $1$ black balls. Now one draws $n \leq N$ of those balls

- with putting the drawn one back

I'd like to find out the probability that the black ball is within the sample (meaning at least once drawn)

**My ideas**

All balls get a number. The black one gets number 1.
$ \Omega = \{(x_1, ..., x_n\}: x_i \in \{1, 2, ..., N\}, 1 \leq i \leq n \}$

$ |\Omega| = N^n$.

$P(A) = 1 - P(A^c)$

$P(A^c) = \frac{N-1}{N}^n$ (since drawing no single black one means in each turn there are only N-1 possible draws).

Therefore $P(A) = 1 - (1 - \frac{1}{N})^n$.

However, searching for probability I found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution and "probability mass function". This should be the one I am looking for, but it's different. How so?

Comment: Sorry, you'd like the probability of what?  Drawing the black ball at least once?  If so, then I expect the confusion arises from the difference between "at least once" and "exactly once".

Comment: @lulu Thank you! I edited it, sorry. It was "Drawing the black ball at least once", yes!

Comment: And that's what your method computes.  True, you can also get that result by summing the terms corresponding to "exactly 1", "exactly 2", ..., up to "exactly N-1"but that's just the long way round.

Comment: @lulu and the Binomial distribution would give me the "exactly 1", "exactly 2", ... ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, but one last question on this topic: With $|\Omega| = N^n$ I have a "Permutation with repetition" (I hope in english literature this is the correct name for it!). This should mean: The order of the elements is important & putting back is possible. But HOW can I say that in my case the order is of any importance?

Comment: You made the order important when you numbered the balls.  That wasn't necessary...you could have just said your sample space had $2^n$ elements (as there were two options, White/Black, at each stage).

Comment: @lulu Ah, I see. But that would have changed the calculation for $P(A)$, wouldn't it? What would it be then? $P(A) = \frac{??}{2^n}$

Comment: No...how you visualize the process doesn't change the process.  Doing it your way distinguishes the events $W_1,W_2$ and $W_2,W_1$.  My way would just say these are both part of $W,W$.  But it all has to come out the same in the end.